# useMutation imported from @apollo/client v 3.3.11

Tags: reactjs, apollo

The problem is:

> Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

When I run react server and use the hook `useMutation` imported from `@apollo/client` I tried to import it from `@apollo/react-hook` but still the same problem.

Any propositions please ?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {ApolloClient,ApolloProvider,gql,InMemoryCache,useMutation} from '@apollo/client'
const CREATE_USER = gql `
    mutation createUser($name:String!  $username:String! $password:String!){
        createUser(name:$name username:$username password:$password){
            id,name,username
        }

    }
`

function App() {
  const [name, setname] = useState("")
  const [username, setusername] = useState("")
  const [passowrd, setpassowrd] = useState("")
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql',
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
  const [createU] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);
 
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <div className="createuser">
        <h2>Create User</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="your name"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="your username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="your password"/>
        <button> Create User</button>
      </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```